# disk partition in Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 to my whole 1tb system due to lack of disk partition time.Now how can I make disk partition in Ubuntu for 1TB hard disk and install windows.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, if I understand your question right you want to create a new partition from you existing partion. [This question and answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/158266/22537) should solve your problem

Comment: It is worth noting that gparted resize can take a LONG time.. it might be easier to back up your data and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

You can boot your computer with a Linux on live USB. Then use the `gparted` utility to resize your Linux partition and prepare the rest of the disk so you can install Windows on it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to know that while the partition in question is mounted, no further actions can be done.

In order for the process to be completed you must:

1. Boot from a live Ubuntu CD or USB first.
2. Start GParted which is an application used to work with disk drives (it can create, erase or modify partitions).
3. Unmount any partitions which may be mounted (the live operating system may mount the swap partition).
4. Modify the partition according to your needs.
5. The above process will leave unallocated space to the disk. There you can create a new partition for Windows to be installed.
6. When finished making the partitions click the check button of GParted to perform the selected actions.

Keep in mind that if you modify the start of operating system's partitions (the left edge as shown in GParted) you will probably has issues with the boot loader and you will have to reinstall the boot loader again.

Credits and full reference at this [link](http://www.howtogeek.com/114503/how-to-resize-your-ubuntu-partitions/) that explains the process with screenshots.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.